# Why is SonarQube giving a transient/private error when class is Serialized?

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube

I have a java class that implements serializable and I'm assuming the variable within the class would also be serialized but SonarQube is complaining to me that it is not.

My snippet of code is shown below:

[image: SonarQube Error]

Comment: Does `BondAxeMarkQuoteUpdate` implement `Serializable`?

Comment: Yeah it implements serializable as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SonarQube marked this line as an error, because [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) doesn't implement [java.io.Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is serializable, but the `bondAxeMarkQuoteUpdates` is `protected` so somebody can assign other non-serializable list to it (e.g. in a subclass).

To solve the problem you can:

1. make the field as `transient`, but it will be ignored during serialization
2. make the field as `private`, so SonarQube can verify that nobody assigned non-serializable list to it
3. change the field type to serializable type (e.g. [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html))

Comment: Mark the field as private is not helping. Sonar still shows this as a bug.

Comment: @Dherik Please create a new StackOverflow question and include your code.

Comment: Hi @agabrys. I discover the problem, I will introduce a new answer for the question

Answer (score 10):

I receive the same error and the solution was turn the class used on the variable as `Serializable`.

For example, this show an error because `Object` is not `Serializable`:

```
private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The simplest solution in the case was turn the second parameter `Serializable`. So, you could use:

```
private Map<String, Serializable> map = new HashMap<>();
```

If you are using your own class (instead of `Object`), you can put the class to `implements Serializable`.

Comment: This does not help in my case unfortunately(

Comment: Serializable is a marker interface. What is the rationale of turning the second parameter as Serializable?

Comment: Serializable is not replacement of Object.

Comment: This is the proper approach, though some clarification is needed. A collection is considered serializable if all child classes are serializable. String is serializable, but Object is not necessarily, as all instances in Java ultimately extend Object, but not all object instances implement Serializable. By using Serializable instead, or by making a custom element class implement Serializable, the collection is enforced through type safety to only contain serializable children, and can therefore be trusted to be a serializable collection.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the rule documentation (that you can open clicking on the ... in your screenshot) : https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1948

> This rule raises an issue on non-Serializable fields, and on collection fields when they are not private (because they could be assigned non-Serializable values externally)

Comment: I understand that but I'm confused as to how I can get for example `private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();` to have `Object` Serialized

Comment: @koala421, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48141335/2387977